# Get list of id's except for latest one from output

Tags: bash, docker

```
~$ docker images --filter=reference="*test-*" --format 'table {{.Repository}}\t{{.CreatedAt}}\t{{.ID}}'

REPOSITORY          CREATED AT                      IMAGE ID
mop-test-image      2019-08-19 09:18:09 +0000 UTC   a16fc65f4d19
mop-test-image      2019-08-19 09:14:11 +0000 UTC   d6a3377f609a
mop-test-image      2019-08-19 09:09:02 +0000 UTC   992aef1d798f
mop-test-image      2019-08-19 09:01:43 +0000 UTC   132bc17ea5cb
mop-test-image      2019-08-19 08:55:59 +0000 UTC   9dfa73010b19
```

How can one get all of the image id's except for the top one (latest CREATED AT one). In other words this list:

```
d6a3377f609a
992aef1d798f
132bc17ea5cb
9dfa73010b19
```

The id numbers will change with time. So including them in answers won't work. It will have to rely on the CREATED AT, which will also change with time.

Answer (score 1):

use the `before`  filter

```
docker rmi -f $(docker images --filter=reference="*test-*" --filter before=a16fc65f4d19 -q)
```

or for automatically find and delete them:

```
docker rmi -f $(docker images  --filter=reference="*test-*" --filter before=`docker images --filter=reference="*test-*" --format '{{.ID}}' | head -1` -q)
```

you need to include `--filter=reference="*test-*"` twice in the second command in case the newest image waht not including in the reference "other images"

Comment: One has to know ID of first image before running this command right?

Comment: Thanks but in that case my suggested command `docker images --format '{{.ID}}' | sed '1d'` may be shorter.

Comment: no you need also to include docker rmi and the reference then they will both equal , beside mybe the first id is from another "REPOSITORY" then you delete all required images ......

Answer (score 1):

To get just docker image `ID` use:

```
docker images --format '{{.ID}}'
```

and to get the all values except top one use:

```
docker images --format '{{.ID}}' | sed '1d'
```

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the output of `docker images` through an `awk` command something like this?

```
awk 'NR > 2 { print $6 }'
```

So

```
docker images --filter=reference="*test-*" --format 'table {{.Repository}}\t{{.CreatedAt}}\t{{.ID}}' | awk 'NR > 2 { print $6 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
docker images --format '{{.CreatedAt}}\t{{.ID}}' | sort | cut -f2
```

The `sort` here is tricky. Because it just so happens that assuming each date is in the same timezone, we can sort lexicographically the list and get proper date order. Then I remove the dates and print just id's.

Now as to "except for the top one" part, just pipe it to `tail -n+2`.

Without it, I would convert the dates in unix epoch date, sort on it and then `cut`:

```
docker images --format '{{.CreatedAt}}\n{{.ID}}' | 
xargs -d$'\n' -n2 bash -c 'printf "%s\t%s\n" "$(date -d "${1//UTC}" +%s)" "$2"' -- | sort -n | cut -f2
```

To make `date` each the date from docker, I only removed the `UTC` suffix and it worked.

Comment: Psst, you were nearly there,what about this: `docker images --filter=reference="*mop-test*" --format '{{.CreatedAt}}\t{{.ID}}' | sort | cut -f2 | sed '$d'`

Comment: I have said `just pipe it to tail -n+2`, but usually `sed` works (way) faster then `tail`, so that's probably a good solution too.